# HTML5 history API to reduce server requests

Tags: browser-history, html5-history

I am trying to develop a search filter and making use of the HTML5 history API to reduce the number of requests sent to the server. If the user checks a checkbox to apply a certain filter I am saving that data in the history state, so that when the user unchecks it I am able to load the data back from the history rather than fetching it again from the server.

When the user checks or unchecks a filter I am changing the window URL to match the filter that was set, for instance if the user tries to filter car brands only of a certain category I change the URL like 'cars?filter-brand[]=1'.

But when mutiple filters are applied I have no way of figuring out whether to load the data from the server or to load it from the history.

At the moment I am using the following code.

```
pushString variable is the new query string that will be created.
var back = [],forward = [];
if(back[back.length-1] === decodeURI(pushString)){   //check last back val against the next URL to be created
                back.pop();
                forward.push(currentLocation);
                history.back();
                return true;
            }else if(forward[forward.length-1] === decodeURI(pushString)){
                forward.pop();
                back.push(currentLocation);
                history.forward();
                return true;
            }else{
                back.push(currentLocation); //add current win location
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if your filters are equivalent.

### Comparing Objects

This is a simple function that takes two files, and lets you know if they're equivalent (note: not prototype safe for simplicity).

```
function objEqual(a, b) {
  function toStr(o){
    var keys = [], values = [];
    for (k in o) {
      keys.push(k);
      values.push(o[k]);
    }
    keys.sort();
    values.sort();
    return JSON.stringify(keys) 
    + JSON.stringify(values);
  }
  return toStr(a) === toStr(b);
}
```

#### [demo](http://codepen.io/brigand/pen/EDLgn)

### Using the URL

Pass the query part of the URL (`window.location.search`) to this function.  It'll give you an object you can compare to another object using the above function.

```
function parseURL(url){
  var obj = {}, parts = url.split("&");
  for (var i=0, part; part = parts[i]; i++) {
    var x = part.split("="), k = x[0], v = x[1];
    obj[k] = v;
  }
  return obj;  
}
```

#### [Demo](http://codepen.io/brigand/pen/FtvCK)

### History API Objects

You can store the objects with the History API.

```
window.history.pushState(someObject, "", "someURL")
```

You can get this object using `history.state` or in a `popState` handler.

### Keeping Track of Things

If you pull out the `toStr` function from the first section, you can serialize the current filters.  You can then store all of the states in an object, and all of the data associated.

When you're pushing a state, you can update your global `cache` object.  This code should be in the handler for the AJAX response.

```
var key = toStr(parseUrl(location.search));
cache[key] = dataFromTheServer;
```

Then abstract your AJAX function to check the cache first.

```
function getFilterResults(filters, callback) {
    var cached = cache[toStr(filters)]
    if (cached != null) callback(cached);
    else doSomeAJAXStuff().then(callback);
}
```

You can also use localstorage for more persistent caching, however this would require more advanced code, and expiring data.

Comment: Your first point is to use a function to compare the object. I am assuming that you are suggesting to compare the new state with the previous state. But to do this I will have to re-fetch the data from the server, then it will be of no use. At the moment I am saving the URL query string section in an array and comparing it with the new filters that are set. But it doesn't work properly.

Comment: I added some more detail about caching the data.

Comment: You have suggested to use arrays to keep the data, is there a way to do this using history state object.